# Java's eqaul's method getting instanceof as false

Tags: java, oop, object, equals, hashcode

I am using a Map to store some data, where my keys are implemented as a concrete classes `KeyType` which has it's hashCode and equals overridden.

when i call the get method in the map, the line `if(other instanceof KeyType)` returns false.
Shouldn't the runtime object be able to know it's concrete class?

EDIT : will include code in a few minutes

Comment: Could you add a bit more code to your question?
What is `other` what is `KeyType` where are you calling this and so on. The question is really vague and can not be answered like this.

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: If it returns false, it means it's not an instance of KeyType. So it means it's null, or something other than a KeyType, which indicates a bug in your code. But you didn't post it, though...

Answer (score 2):

By calling [`Map#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) you are getting the value and not the key. You might want to be sure that your value is also a type of `KeyType` or else it won't work.

Comment: From my standpoint he is making an assumption what the question is *supposed* to mean. If the question is unclear though we should first make sure we clarify it so that other people can benefit from it instead of us being left with some assumption and a badly worded question.